# What const declaration mean when used with virtual function in C++?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

How to read the below line in C++?

```
virtual Real NPV() const =0;
```

I understand that it is a virtual function, and the return type of the function is `Real` (what is `Real`?). But what does `const=0` in the same line refer to?

[image]

Comment: *what is Real?* a custom type that must be defined somewhere before the definition of `Instrument`

Comment: for `=0` read about pure virtual functions

Comment: The  =0 at the end of a virtual function indicates that it is a 'pure virtual function'  i.e. an abstract function. Derived classes have to override it and provide their own implementation.

Comment: In C++, `Real` will usually be an alias for some floating point type such as `float` or `double`. The `const` means that the function won't modify the "logical" state of the object of which it's a member. It might still modify a few things though--for example, if you're doing multi-threading, it's fairly common for an object to contain a `mutex` (or similar) to protect access to data, and when it does, that `mutex` will often be `mutable` so a `const` member function can change the mutex to allow exclusive access to the protected data.